# Show create table in hbase

Tags: hbase, create-table

Is there an equivalent to hive: `show create table <tablename>;` in hbase?

I have several tables with table splits defined. using Describe `<tablename>` doesn't show this detail.

For example, if I create table TEST1 like:

```
hbase(main):001:0> create 'TEST1', {NAME =>'D',COMPRESSION=>'SNAPPY'} , {SPLITS => ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0']}

hbase(main):001:0> describe 'TEST1'
DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                   ENABLED
 'TEST1', {NAME => 'D', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPR true
 ESSION => 'SNAPPY', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', IN_MEMORY =>
  'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
1 row(s) in 6.5080 seconds
```

Notice that the describe doesn't show the splits. How can I do this in a way that it shows the splits?

I understand that I can see this info using HBase master table detail webpage; but I need to see this in the shell. That way I can run this shell for several tables and see the splits.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from HBase 1.4.0 you can use `list_regions` command from shell to get this information. This command was added by [HBASE-14925](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14925).

```
hbase(main):009:0> list_regions 'TEST1'
                      SERVER_NAME |                                             REGION_NAME |  START_KEY |    END_KEY |  SIZE |   REQ |   LOCALITY |
 -------------------------------- | ------------------------------------------------------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----- | ----- | ---------- |
 192.168.0.88,16020,1554497956619 |  TEST1,,1554323951962.89d0941894de38e0ae9341c8b6084d30. |            |          0 |     0 |     0 |        0.0 |
 192.168.0.88,16020,1554497956619 | TEST1,0,1554323951962.5a8ef486ce02f275b934f29a32420012. |          0 |          1 |     0 |     0 |        0.0 |
 192.168.0.88,16020,1554497956619 | TEST1,1,1554323951962.3db5376ce21369d512d78e5f1fff1bba. |          1 |          2 |     0 |     0 |        0.0 |
 192.168.0.88,16020,1554497956619 | TEST1,2,1554323951962.e1f0c483458599d7dcd0ed5d30003545. |          2 |          3 |     0 |     0 |        0.0 |
 192.168.0.88,16020,1554497956619 | TEST1,3,1554323951962.15647aa5d5e171221e6b83df6b657601. |          3 |          4 |     0 |     0 |        0.0 |
 192.168.0.88,16020,1554497956619 | TEST1,4,1554323951962.54d28b093d7061067bd51df94f0461bf. |          4 |          5 |     0 |     0 |        0.0 |
 192.168.0.88,16020,1554497956619 | TEST1,5,1554323951962.c3a88c6e5ad002f742b7673a3603846a. |          5 |          6 |     0 |     0 |        0.0 |
 192.168.0.88,16020,1554497956619 | TEST1,6,1554323951962.92e954f21167a38914a127564af6d1b0. |          6 |          7 |     0 |     0 |        0.0 |
 192.168.0.88,16020,1554497956619 | TEST1,7,1554323951962.689cfe19e275404643e3e76d2931c846. |          7 |          8 |     0 |     0 |        0.0 |
 192.168.0.88,16020,1554497956619 | TEST1,8,1554323951962.14d0ed9c3f50c107259c44ce8d0fb1a3. |          8 |          9 |     0 |     0 |        0.0 |
 192.168.0.88,16020,1554497956619 | TEST1,9,1554323951962.81c6d967c6c38590bb16a276f0cf8b55. |          9 |            |     0 |     0 |        0.0 |
 11 rows
Took 0.0410 seconds
```

To get the regions on an earlier version you'd need to collect it from `hbase:meta` table. The relevant parts are `STARTKEY` and `ENDKEY`.

```
hbase(main):016:0> scan 'hbase:meta', { FILTER => "PrefixFilter('TEST1')", COLUMNS => "info:regioninfo" }
ROW                                       COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                           
 TEST1,,1554323951962.89d0941894de38e0ae9 column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1554499886995, value={ENCODED => 89d0941894de38e0ae9341c8b6084d30, NAME => 'TEST1,,1
 341c8b6084d30.                           554323951962.89d0941894de38e0ae9341c8b6084d30.', STARTKEY => '', ENDKEY => '0'}                                       
 TEST1,0,1554323951962.5a8ef486ce02f275b9 column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1554499887022, value={ENCODED => 5a8ef486ce02f275b934f29a32420012, NAME => 'TEST1,0,
 34f29a32420012.                          1554323951962.5a8ef486ce02f275b934f29a32420012.', STARTKEY => '0', ENDKEY => '1'}                                     
 TEST1,1,1554323951962.3db5376ce21369d512 column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1554499886995, value={ENCODED => 3db5376ce21369d512d78e5f1fff1bba, NAME => 'TEST1,1,
 d78e5f1fff1bba.                          1554323951962.3db5376ce21369d512d78e5f1fff1bba.', STARTKEY => '1', ENDKEY => '2'}                                     
 TEST1,2,1554323951962.e1f0c483458599d7dc column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1554499887010, value={ENCODED => e1f0c483458599d7dcd0ed5d30003545, NAME => 'TEST1,2,
 d0ed5d30003545.                          1554323951962.e1f0c483458599d7dcd0ed5d30003545.', STARTKEY => '2', ENDKEY => '3'}                                     
 TEST1,3,1554323951962.15647aa5d5e171221e column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1554499886982, value={ENCODED => 15647aa5d5e171221e6b83df6b657601, NAME => 'TEST1,3,
 6b83df6b657601.                          1554323951962.15647aa5d5e171221e6b83df6b657601.', STARTKEY => '3', ENDKEY => '4'}                                     
 TEST1,4,1554323951962.54d28b093d7061067b column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1554499886982, value={ENCODED => 54d28b093d7061067bd51df94f0461bf, NAME => 'TEST1,4,
 d51df94f0461bf.                          1554323951962.54d28b093d7061067bd51df94f0461bf.', STARTKEY => '4', ENDKEY => '5'}                                     
 TEST1,5,1554323951962.c3a88c6e5ad002f742 column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1554499887008, value={ENCODED => c3a88c6e5ad002f742b7673a3603846a, NAME => 'TEST1,5,
 b7673a3603846a.                          1554323951962.c3a88c6e5ad002f742b7673a3603846a.', STARTKEY => '5', ENDKEY => '6'}                                     
 TEST1,6,1554323951962.92e954f21167a38914 column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1554499886980, value={ENCODED => 92e954f21167a38914a127564af6d1b0, NAME => 'TEST1,6,
 a127564af6d1b0.                          1554323951962.92e954f21167a38914a127564af6d1b0.', STARTKEY => '6', ENDKEY => '7'}                                     
 TEST1,7,1554323951962.689cfe19e275404643 column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1554499887009, value={ENCODED => 689cfe19e275404643e3e76d2931c846, NAME => 'TEST1,7,
 e3e76d2931c846.                          1554323951962.689cfe19e275404643e3e76d2931c846.', STARTKEY => '7', ENDKEY => '8'}                                     
 TEST1,8,1554323951962.14d0ed9c3f50c10725 column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1554499887020, value={ENCODED => 14d0ed9c3f50c107259c44ce8d0fb1a3, NAME => 'TEST1,8,
 9c44ce8d0fb1a3.                          1554323951962.14d0ed9c3f50c107259c44ce8d0fb1a3.', STARTKEY => '8', ENDKEY => '9'}                                     
 TEST1,9,1554323951962.81c6d967c6c38590bb column=info:regioninfo, timestamp=1554499886995, value={ENCODED => 81c6d967c6c38590bb16a276f0cf8b55, NAME => 'TEST1,9,
 16a276f0cf8b55.                          1554323951962.81c6d967c6c38590bb16a276f0cf8b55.', STARTKEY => '9', ENDKEY => ''}                                      
11 row(s)
Took 0.0134 seconds
```